# JSON serialization using recursion and reflection. (Issue with arrays)

Tags: c#, .net, json, recursion, reflection

I'm currently attempting to make my own JSON serialization method, but I have a issue with arrays when i call my "serialize" method which is called like this:

```
string person = MyJsonConverter.Serialize(new Clerk("Alexander", 1999, new List<string> { "Computer Science", "Web Developer" }));
Console.WriteLine(person);
```

Which produces the following:

```
{"Skills": ["Capacity": "4", "Count": "2"], "Name": "Alexander", "YearOfBirth": "1999"}
```

But should produce this:

```
{"Skills": ["Computer Science", "Web Developer"], "Name": "Alexander", "YearOfBirth": "1999"}
```

The method in question that I need help with is this, I'm not entirely sure what I do wrong, but for some reason it takes the properties of the array and not the values of the array.

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        stringBuilder.Append($"[");
    else
        stringBuilder.Append($"{{");

    foreach (var property in properties)
        if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            stringBuilder.Append($"\"{property.Name}\": \"{property.GetValue(obj)}\", ");
        else
            stringBuilder.Append($"\"{property.Name}\": {Serialize(property.GetValue(obj))}, ");

    string temp = stringBuilder.ToString().Trim().Remove(stringBuilder.ToString().Length - 2);

    stringBuilder.Clear();
    stringBuilder.Append(temp);

    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        stringBuilder.Append($"]");
    else
        stringBuilder.Append($"}}");

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it required that you write your own parser? You could use newtonsoft nuget and call it a day.

Comment: @Rafa Yes, since it's for a assignment. I already know about JsonConvert etc... But I have to make my own for this assignment.

Comment: [`typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())` terrible idea](https://dotnetfiddle.net/psy7cI) as `IEnumerable<object>` is not assgnable from `IEnumerable<SomeValueType>`

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that it works as expected. For lists you need to iterate through its elements. Also for nested objects, you would need to call your `Serialize` in a recursive way.

Comment: @Selvin I tried obj.IsArray and a bunch of others, that method seemed to work the best in my case.

Comment: [Sytem.Collections.IEnumerable is better](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aULcr9)

Comment: @Selvin IIRC in C# [ ] arrays derive from IList which derive from IEnumerable, so obviously it's going to be true... Which is the point.

Comment: @AlexanderBruun click first link

Comment: @Selvin Oh, I see the difference. Will update it to your suggestion :) Does it have to do with the fact that int is a primitive type and doesn't come from object? Or is it another reason?

Comment: you serializer is wrong as you assume that json should start with `{` or `[` ... **`3` or `"some text"` is valid json** ... next `if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))` you should cast to IEnumerable and iterate then callinfg fixed Serialize for every object

Comment: @Selvin I understand the first part of valid json, but not the second part. Could you possibly make a answer to the question so I can see what you are trying to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    if (!obj.GetType().IsPrimitive && obj.GetType() != typeof(string))
    {
        bool isArray = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) ? true : false;

        if (isArray)
            stringBuilder.Append($"[");
        else
            stringBuilder.Append($"{{");

        if (!isArray)
            foreach (var property in properties)
                if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    stringBuilder.Append($"\"{property.Name}\": \"{property.GetValue(obj)}\", ");
                else
                    stringBuilder.Append($"\"{property.Name}\": {Serialize(property.GetValue(obj))}, ");
        else
            foreach (var i in obj as IEnumerable)
                if (i.GetType().IsPrimitive || i.GetType() == typeof(string))
                    stringBuilder.Append($"\"{i}\", ");
                else
                    stringBuilder.Append($"{Serialize(i)}, ");

        stringBuilder.Remove(stringBuilder.ToString().Length - 2, 2);

        if (isArray)
            stringBuilder.Append($"]");
        else
            stringBuilder.Append($"}}");
    }
    else
        stringBuilder.Append(obj.ToString());

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

It might not be the prettiest, but it works.

I'm still open for suggestions.

Comment: This code will throw Null Reference Exception whenever you send a Object where a certain filed was not added or sent as null. Add another `if` condition on after `StringBuilder` initialization  which will stop the recursion. `if(obj == null) return null;` otherwise GREAT JOB. Nicely done.